# Published sns message from lambda function not received by device

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a very simple lambda function that publishes a message to a topic like so:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sns = new AWS.SNS()
const TOPIC_ARN = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<topic ARN>";
const TARGET_ARN = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<target ARN>";

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    return sns.publish({
        Message: JSON.stringify({
     "default": "any value", 
     "GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"message body\", \"title\": \"message title \", \"sound\":\"default\" } , \"data\" : {\"key\" : \"value\", \"key2\" : \"value\" } }"
     }),
        TargetArn: TARGET_ARN,
        // TopicArn: TOPIC_ARN, also tried this same result
    })
    .promise()
    .then(() => ({statusCode: 204, body: ''}))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return {statusCode: 500, body: 'sns-error'};
    });
};
```

The function executes without issue and I can see a success event in my cloud watch logs.

**The problem is that the Notification is never received by the device.**

I know that the ARN is correct because I can go to the SNS console and publish the same message to the device and it is received.

I can also spin up a nodejs application on my local machine and publish the same message to the ARN and it is received, no problem.

I also configured Delivery Status Logging on the *Platform Application* and I can see a success response like so from the lambda function:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageMD5Sum": "<sting of numbers>",
        "messageId": "<sting of numbers>",
        "timestamp": "2021-07-23 15:35:02.167"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "deliveryId": "<sting of text>",
        "destination": "<ARN>",
        "providerResponse": "{\"multicast_id\":<sting of numbers>,\"success\":1,\"failure\":0,\"canonical_ids\":0,\"results\":[{\"message_id\":\"0:<sting of text>\"}]}",
        "dwellTimeMs": 28,
        "attempts": 1,
        "token": <correct device token>,
        "statusCode": 200
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
}
```

***Why is the lambda function the only method where the SNS notification is not being received by the device?***

***SOLUTION***

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const sns = new AWS.SNS()
const TOPIC_ARN = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<topic ARN>";
const TARGET_ARN = "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:<target ARN>";

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    return sns.publish({
        Message: JSON.stringify({
     "default": "any value", 
     "GCM": "{ \"notification\": { \"body\": \"message body\", \"title\": \"message title \", \"sound\":\"default\" } , \"data\" : {\"key\" : \"value\", \"key2\" : \"value\" } }"
     }),
        MessageStructure: 'json', //this solved the problem
        TargetArn: TARGET_ARN,
    })
    .promise()
    .then(() => ({statusCode: 204, body: ''}))
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        return {statusCode: 500, body: 'sns-error'};
    });
};
```

Adding *MessageStructure: 'json'* solved the problem.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: If you compare a SUCCESS log from the Lambda publish with a SUCCESS log from a console publish, are there any differences?

Comment: Neither show any errors, but they have different success details.

Comment: Can you post an example of each?

Answer (score -1):

Edited original question to include answer:

Adding *MessageStructure: 'json'* solved the problem.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: you should answer the question and accept your answer.